# com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier - Failed to fetch default config version for service (only on localhost)

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I'm using Cloud Endpoints Frameworks (2.0.1) for Java as part of my final year project and have been relatively successful with it so far. 
I don't have any problems when deploying to my appspot.com domain, however, I am running into some problems when deploying locally.

(Any references to my-project-id in the following code blocks are aliases for my actual google cloud project id)

I have a valid openapi descriptor (openapi.json) of an annotated @API class which I am deploying to cloud endpoints using "gcloud service-management deploy openapi.json".
The command returns successfully:

```
Service Configuration [2017-02-23r0] uploaded for service [api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog]
```

I then map the returned config_id to the correct endpoints_api_service in my app.yaml

```
endpoints_api_service:
  name: api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog
  config_id: 2017-02-23r0
```

This service is listed by the gcloud cli tool using "gcloud service-management list"

```
    NAME                                                           TITLE
    storage-component.googleapis.com                 Google Cloud Storage
    api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog         api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog
    etc...
```

and "gcloud service-management configs list --service api.endpoints.my-project-id.cloud.goog"

```
CONFIG_ID        SERVICE_NAME
2017-02-23r0     api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog
... other version configs
```

and is accessible on my appspot.com domain (I can call the endpoint and receive the correct response)

I am trying to deploy my project on localhost using the maven appengine plugin for java (mvn appengine:devserver), but upon jetty startup I'm hit with the following Exception:

```
 WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext...

com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException: Failed to fetch default config version for service 'api.endpoints.<my-project-id>.cloud.goog'. No versions exist!
at com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetchLatestServiceVersion(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:155)
....
```

The deployment then gets stuck in an endless cycle of trying to start jetty, and being hit with that error message, and restarting etc. Any attempts to access localhost:8080 result in a "503: Service not found" error

I assumed that the local deployment of my app would be able to access the service config that was deployed using "gcloud service-management deploy", in the same way that the appspot.com deployment can, but is this not the case?
Looking at the source for ServiceConfigSupplier.getchLatestServiceVersion() I gather that serviceManagement.services().configs().list(my-service-name).execute().getServiceConfigs() is returning an empty list, but why is this only occurring locally?

**Extra Information**

my ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME environment variable matches 'api.endpoints.my-project-id.cloud.goog'

I noticed that there was an update (1.0.2) to com.google.api.config a few days ago, and it has a dependency on an older version of com.google.api.services.servicemanagement (dependent on v1-rev14-1.22.0 with the newest version being v1-rev340-1.22.0)
I doubt this is the problem, but I thought I would mention it, as it contains classes relevant to the exception (ServiceManagement is used by ServiceConfigSupplier, which is throwing the exception). Perhaps there is an inconsistency in where they are looking for the service configs?

I'm quite stumped tbh, it's a bit over my head. I would dislike having to remove Endpoints, as I'm starting to like it, but we also can't really lose usage of our devserver either. I hope someone can shed a little bit of light on this issue.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm using Java and have the same issue.

Comment: Hi Sam Holden, were you able to solve the issue? A document related to this was recently updated.  

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java

There is also a sample located here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend

Let me know! Thank you.

Comment: @FrankNatividad I am seeing almost this exact error following the quickstart you provided in your link.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but when I first started playing with this stuff in early March 2017 and was running version 135 (I think) of gcloud cli, I could do the `mvn appengine:run` successfully. I know it doesn't fix the problem but you might be able to rollback using `gcloud components update --version 135.0.0` to test it.

Comment: I'm writing a complete solution for this issue atm. This is a hidden permissions issue. For now, you can get past this by using `gcloud auth application-default login`. This will request necessary permissions and update default application credentials.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a fix but I was able to work around the problem by using the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493548/1410035.

Namely, commenting out the `ServiceManagementConfigFilter`:

> b) Comment out the ServiceManagementConfigFilter from web.xml , ie,
>
> ```
> <!--
>     <filter>
>       <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
>       <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
>    </filter>
> -->
>
> <!--    
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
>     <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> -->
> ```

Note that you have to comment out the `filter` **and** the `filter-mapping` and they aren't right next to each other in the file.

I found that I didn't need to remove the scaling block as mentioned in point 'a' in the linked answer.

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to a permission issue if you have pulled all recent updates. `git pull` Also, check that your Cloud SDK is up-to-date by using: `gcloud components update`.

Assuming you followed the instructions listed at https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java. To get around this issue you can create a service account with necessary permissions or use the command `gcloud auth application-default login`.

You can setup a service account using the Cloud SDK gcloud at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing

Please let me know if you have anymore questions.

As for the command `gcloud auth application-default login`. According to the help description:

> Obtains user access credentials via a web flow and puts them in the
>   well-known location for Application Default Credentials to use them as
>   a proxy for a service account.

When you used this command it obtains credentials for gcloud your Gmail Account. something@gmail.com and then stores the credentials in a location known to contain application credentials.

Comment: This eventually works for me. I need to send the first curl to the service to wake it up and it'll return the same 503 response as before. Once it's up (you'll see a flood of stuff in the log) it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with "gradle appengineRun" but on IntelliJ Idea project I had to replace all the ${endpoints.project.id} in web.xml and appengine-web.xml to run/debug localhost from IntelliJ (imported from gradle sources, installed Google Cloud Tools plugin and set up run/debug configuration from Tools/GoogleCloudTools/Run on a local App Engine Standard dev server).

My error was:
Failed to fetch default config version for service 'echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog'. No versions exist!

[cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) docs only have Maven build example Gradle build is at [github.com](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to bare in mind is your service account has the right permission, your service account is something looks like the following

```
[project ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
```

By default, it is Project(Editor), at least you need to provide it as Service Controller role.

If it is gone, then you can follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) to add back in.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you've changed the Google Cloud project you're trying to authenticate to (if someone else has changed the project, this can happen when you pull changes from source control). In this case, the service account credentials that you were using for the old project will no longer be valid, and you can authenticate to the new project by running:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this fairly similar error,

> endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException:
>   Failed to fetch service config (status code 404): The service config
>   name and config id could not be found. Double check that filter
>   initialization parameters endpoints.projectId and
>   endpoints.serviceName are correctly set.

and the issue for me was having *ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION* environment variable specified in my appengine-web.xml. So basically, **deleting** those lines was enough in my case (Since endpoints uses the most recent *ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION* [if not provided any.](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-management-python/issues/68)):

```
<env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I hadn't deployed the open API.
So running the below fixed the issue:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.json
```