# How to avoid the "ServiceConfigException: No versions exist!" error while implementing API Management with Cloud Endpoints Frameworks?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, error-handling, google-cloud-endpoints-v2, ibm-api-management

I've built a test API in a new Maven-based App Engine Standard project created in Eclipse. Upon adding API Management and deploying on production server, I get a 500 response when trying out the API on the Endpoints Portal. Error logs in the dashboard show the following exception:

```
endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException: 
Failed to fetch default config version for service 'networking-1088.appspot.com'.
No versions exist!
```

I checked out similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144500/serviceconfigexception-when-api-management-is-added) but I have used the project ID as the service name consistently across files, have not included service version, and have used all the necessary boilerplate code from the documentation.

Below are relevant snippets from my files:

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>

    <endpoints.project.id>networking-1088</endpoints.project.id>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
            <version>0.80.0-alpha</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [START api_management] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
        <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [END api_management] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.71</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resources>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resources>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- [START endpoints_plugin] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- plugin configuration -->
                <hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- [END endpoints_plugin] -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.iitbaapune.app.RegistrantEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- [START api_management] -->
<!-- Add a filter that fetches the service config from service management. -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Add a filter that performs Endpoints logging and monitoring. -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
        <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
        <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- [END api_management] -->
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
  <!-- [START env_variables] -->
<env-variables>
    <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="networking-1088.appspot.com" />
</env-variables>
<!-- [END env_variables] -->
```

How can I get rid of this error while retaining API management?

Comment: Have you deployed your service configuration with `gcloud endpoints services deploy`?

Comment: Thanks for helping troubleshoot, Rose! Yes, I did deploy the service configurations. I see the following 4 configurations deployed: 
2019-02-12r3  networking-1088.appspot.com,
2019-02-12r2  networking-1088.appspot.com,
2019-02-12r1  networking-1088.appspot.com,
2019-02-12r0  networking-1088.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I had the same issue. Uncommenting the endpoints-api-configuration filter, made error go away but left me without authentication support.

Eventually while rebuilding the entire project from the example provided [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend), I noticed that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was the cause of my `com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter doFilter: Rejecting this API request due to config loading error.`

```
 <env-variables>
   <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com" />
   <env-var name="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" value="WEB-INF/myproject-firebase-adminsdk-xyz.json" />
 </env-variables>
```

Omitting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` line made the error go away in my case...